# Can I display groups sum and grand total of all groups in Tabulator?

Tags: group-by, sum, tabulator

I created table by Tabulator to use "GroupBy".
I could get "group by sum".
but I want to show the grand total of all groups too.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `columnCalcs` option to do this, if you set it to a value of "both" it will show the group calculations and the column calculations:

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    columnCalcs:"both", //show column calculations at top and bottom of table and in groups
});
```